# How Do I Change the Coordinates of an Object(Visual Basic)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to make a Pong game in VB 2010. I added two RectangleShapes for the paddles, and to get one of them to move, I was going to use the arrow keys. I thought that a KeyDown event procedure would do the job, but it's not going as planned. Could someone help me please? The code excerpt is down below:

```
'Paddle Movement
Private Sub frmMyPong_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Dim redX As Integer = rectRed.Location.X
    Dim redY As Integer = rectRed.Location.Y
    Dim blueX As Integer = rectBlue.Location.X
    Dim blueY As Integer = rectBlue.Location.Y

    If Keys.Up Then     'Moves paddle up
        redY -= 1
    End If
    If Keys.Down Then   'Moves paddle down
        redY += 1
    End If
    If Keys.Right Then      'Moves paddle to the right
        redX -= 1
    End If
    If Keys.Left Then       'Moves paddle to the left
        redX += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "it's not going as planned" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the position of the paddles in variables (redX, redY), and then updating those variables instead of the actual paddles.

It's like remembering where the paddles are, then imagining where they will be.

You should rather just increment the position of the paddles directly:

```
Private Sub frmMyPong_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If Keys.Up Then     'Moves paddle up
        rectRed.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y - 1) 
    End If
    If Keys.Down Then   'Moves paddle down
        rectRed.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y + 1) 
    End If
    If Keys.Right Then      'Moves paddle to the right
        rectRed.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X + 1, Label1.Location.Y) 
    End If
    If Keys.Left Then       'Moves paddle to the left
        rectRed.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X - 1, Label1.Location.Y) 
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, once you get this working, have a look at:

- The `Select Case` operator - which would make your conditions easier to read
- Separating you Paddle representation (the rectangles) from the concept of a Paddle - if you made a separate Paddle class, with properties such as location, length, etc, it would help you manage your program better as it becomes larger.

Comment: I tried what you suggested: rectRed.Location.Y -= 1, but I just get the error: "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment". Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, you can't directly change the Location of a control, instead you need to give it a new location.   I have fixed the example.

Answer (score 0):

This would work ,,, Adding new Sub and trigger it with arrows

```
If Keys.Up Then     'Moves paddle up
    redY -= 1
       moveitem()          ' this will fire new function
End If
If Keys.Down Then   'Moves paddle down
    redY += 1
       moveitem()        ' this will fire new function
End If
If Keys.Right Then      'Moves paddle to the right
    redX -= 1
       moveitem()  ' this will fire new function
End If
If Keys.Left Then       'Moves paddle to the left
    redX += 1
       moveitem()  ' this will fire new function
End If
```

---

and then you add

---

```
Private sub moveitem() 
   rectRed.Location = new point(redX,redY)
End sub
```

Comment: This code uses vaguely scoped variables (redX, redY). It is better to create sub/function with parameters (`moveitem(X as integer, Y as integer)`) and use that - much easier to understand your code after two weeks or so :)

Comment: He already declare it in the upper lines he only have to replace the IF statements so he will be able to fire the function